# Pass data to transcluded element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a directive that organizes a displays data grouped by date. I also want to be able to specify a directive that will display the individual rows. In a perfect world it would look something like this (but nice and pretty)

```
Friday, Oct 28
    [some directive html]
    [some directive html]
    [some directive html]
Saturday, Oct 29
    [some directive html]
Sunday, Oct 30
    [some directive html]
    [some directive html]
...
```

This obviously doesn't work, so if you have a better approach please tell me, but I was hoping to be able to do something along these lines:

```
app.directive('dateOrganized', [function(){
    return {
        template:
            '<div>' +
                '<div ng-repeat="organizedDate in organizedDate">' +
                    '<div>{{organizedDate.date | date}}</div>' +
                    '<div ng-repeat="item in organizedDate.items">' +
                        '{{rowDirectiveHtml}}' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>',
        scope: {
            organizedDates: '=',
            rowDirectiveHtml: '='
        }
        ...
    };
}])

app.directive('itemRow', [function(){
    return {
        template: '<div>{{item.data}}</div>',
        scope: {
            item: '='
        }
    };
}]);
```

then use it like this:

```
<div data-organized organized-dates="stuff" row-directive-html="<div item-row item=\"item\" />" />
```

I know this is super ugly (and doesn't work, but I'm sure I could get it working with a few tweaks) so what I am really asking, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to pass the html in the `row-directive-html`? Will it change?

Comment: You should look into [`$transclude` function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-link-) - injected into a controller or a 5th paramter to the `link` function. You should also consider passing a template (which is what it is) as a child element rather than an attribute. But overall, a good answer to this question will need to touch on a number of concepts, so, it's better to be familiar with these fundamental concepts first.

Comment: Yes the rows will change so I need it to be flexible. @new dev thanks for the tip. I'll look into it.

Comment: @new dev, I've used simple transcluding before, but is it possible to pass my item into the transcluded directive? And wouldn't that end up being a sibling scope rather than a child scope?

Comment: @CodesLikeA_Mokey, you need to use a manual transclude, rather than `<ng-transclude>`, which allows you to specify whatever scope you want to link the transcluded content against. Also, since the template is actually a template for `ng-repeat`, you might need to manually `$compile` the directive inner template rather than using `template` property... Like I said, it's a bit of a complex question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question is more complicated than might appear, so let's break it down.

What you are building is a directive that accepts a partial template - `<div item-row item="item" />` - ***and*** that template uses (or linked against a scope with) an inner variable - `item` - that is not defined in the outer scope by the user; its meaning is defined by your directive and your user "discovers" it by reading the documentation of your directive. I typically name such "magic" variables with a prefixed `$`, e.g. `$item`.

**Step 1**

Instead of passing a template as an HTML-as-string via attribute binding, pass it as contents and transclude that content. Transcluding allows you to bind the transcluded content against an arbitrary scope:

```
<foo>
  <div>my item is: {{$item}}</div>
</foo>
```

```
.directive("foo", function(){
  return {
    scope: {},
    transclude: true,
    template: "<h1>I am foo</h1><placeholder></placeholder>",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transclude){

      scope.$item = "magic variable";

      transclude(scope, function(clonedContent){
        element.find("placeholder").replaceWith(clonedContent);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

The above will place the template `<div>my item is: {{$item}}</div>` (could be any template you specify) where the directive `foo` decides, and will link against a scope that has `$item` defined.

**Step 2**

But the added complexity of your directive is that it uses `ng-repeat`, which by itself accepts a template, and the template your directive receives needs to be used as a template of `ng-repeat`.

With just the approach above, this would not work, since by the time `link` runs, `ng-repeat` will have already transcluded its own content before you had a chance to apply yours.

One way to address that is to manually `$compile` the template of `foo` instead of using the `template` property. Prior to compiling, we will have a chance to place the intended template where needed:

```
.directive("foo", function($compile){
  return {
    scope: {},
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transclude){

      scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4];

      var template = '<h1>I am foo</h1>\
                      <div ng-repeat="$item in items">\
                        <placeholder></placeholder>\
                      </div>';
      var templateEl = angular.element(template);

      transclude(scope, function(clonedContent){
        templateEl.find("placeholder").replaceWith(clonedContent);

        $compile(templateEl)(scope, function(clonedTemplate){
          element.append(clonedTemplate);
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/aZKFqPJmPlfTVRffB0Cc?p=preview)**

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. The whole ng-repeat was throwing me off and I didn't want to hack in an ugly solution. Once again, great job.

Comment: Nice solution with good explanation, helped to solve the exact problem in my project.